# List zip file which may or may not end with numbers

Tags: linux, shell, command, zip

I wanted to list all the zip files that may or may not end in numbers like below:

```
job_customer_old_0.1.zip
job_customer_old.zip
job_customer_0.2.zip
job_customer.zip

find "directtory_path" -name job_customer[_0-9]*\.zip
```

I expect only job_customer.zip and job_customer_0.2.zip. 
But I get all 4.

Help please.

Comment: Drop the asterisk: it goes for every amount of digits, including zero amount :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-name` from `find` matches like shell. So the `[_0-9]` matches a single one(!) character that is `_` or a number. Then `*` matches any(!) character any number of times.

If you want to use regexes with `find` use the `-regex` option. Ex:

```
# creating MCVE
xargs touch <<EOF
job_customer_old_0.1.zip
job_customer_old.zip
job_customer_0.2.zip
job_customer.zip
EOF

find . -regex '\./job_customer[_0-9\.]*\.zip'
```

This will print `job_customer.zip` and `job_customer_0.2.zip`. Note that in `_0.2` there is also a dot `.` so I added that inside braces `[_0-9\.]`. With `-regextype` `find` option you can specify `find` to use different flavours of regex. Note that the regex matches whole part, not only the filename, so probably you would have to go with ex. `find "directtory_path" -regex './directtory_path/job_customer[_0-9\.]*\.zip'`

Comment: Kamil, This works fine if I am in current directory. To find with absolute path, this does not work.
find "$path" -regex '$path/job_customer[_0-9\.]*\.zip' does not seem to give any output

Comment: The `'` does not expand variables. Use `"` to expand variables. `find "$path" -regex "$path"'/job_customer...'`

Comment: Thanks find $path -type f -regex "$path\/job/job_LOAN_ENTITLEMENT[_0-9\.]*\.zip"